# How to get a definition list wrapped in anchors to display horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've created a [jsfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/Trxhn/) and the sample HTML and CSS is below.

I've removed the margins, the padding, and I've set everything to display inline, yet I can't get each anchor to sit side by side.

I've tried all that I would expect to work, but CSS often doesn't do what I expect.

Any help or insight with this will be much appreciated.

The HTML:

```
<dl>
  <a href="#">
    <dt>One</dt>
    <dd><img src="//imageshack.us/a/img22/2964/puppies4.jpg" height='100' width='100' /></dd>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <dt>Two</dt>
    <dd><img src='//imageshack.us/a/img519/5132/im20cagnolininu8.jpg' width='100' height='100' /></dd>
  </a>
</dl>
```

The CSS:

```
dl { 
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    a {
        border: 1px solid green;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        dt,dd { margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline;}
    }
}​
```

Comment: chk this http://jsfiddle.net/Trxhn/1/

Comment: That works, so you should add it as the answer.  Why does the float make a difference?

Comment: `dt` and `dd` tags should have `dl` tag as parent. even though this wrong html is rendered by browsers, this still ends up being a problem. block level `dd` wrapped inside an inline `a` blew your styling up. this is why the use of `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;` for `a` made the styling alright. instead of using `dl, dt, dd` for this kind of content, use `div` my friend. much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CSS` has wrong structure (nested brackets), fix that and everything should look OK. In your `jsfiddle` this error is also present.

```
dl { 
    border: 1px solid yellow; }

a {
            border: 1px solid green;
            display: inline;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; }

dt,dd { margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline;}
```

Comment: I thought nested CSS was valid? When I change it to unnested it displays horizontally, but a bit higgledy piggledy.

Comment: My mistake, I've been using SASS for so long now it's difficult to remember what constitutes valid CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get it displaying horizontally.

1) Change the anchor tags display from inline to inline-block. 
2) Add a left float to the anchor tag

I think that the first will be the easier to implement as you don't need to deal with the collapsed dl element that the floating causes in the second way.

Comment: The problem is not with the anchor, but with CSS structure itself.

Comment: Hi. I corrected the CSS structure in jsbin and it didn't seem to make the links show horizontally. Setting it to inline-block did. I agree that the CSS structure needed changing also.